# How to animate UI position for different aspect ratio screens?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know how to make a moving animation of an UI object, but how to make it supporting different aspect ratio screens?

For example, I have an UI object_1 in the left-lower corner and object_2 in the right-upper corner, both adjusted its position relative to the screen's corners. I want to make an UI image moving from object_1 to object_2.

The problem is that object_1 and object_2 are at different positions (even different ratio according to screen ratio) in different resolutions. Then how can I make the moving animation supporting different resolutions?

Thanks for any advice!

Screenshots:
1 Moving starting point where the left-lower checkbox is on 18:9 screen.
[image]

2 Moving ending point where the left-lower checkbox is on 18:9 screen.
[image]

3 Moving starting point, changed to 16:9 screen, and the screenshot shows that the position of the finger image does not match where the checkbox is.
[image]

4 Moving ending point on 16:9 screen, same problem with the above one.
[image]

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html , This may help

Comment: @AhmedAli Thanks, I understand how recttransform and anchors works, however how to make the animation supporting this?

Comment: The animation will support that! Because you have set the `pivots`

Comment: Right now I had an animation of moving image from object_1 to object_2, and it works fine in 18:9 screen. However if I change it to 16:9 screen, the start and end positions will not be exactly where object_1 and object_2 are.

Comment: Yes that's a major issue with UI, because your images are not respect to screen resolution. You have to resize your images according to screen's resolutions. I am not saying that your animations will be as it is in other resolutions but it will be some how fit

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what you mean, please see the new screen shot I added in the question. They can explain well about the situation.

Comment: Create a `panel` (parent container) then make all *UI* it's child and set the `panel` width and height to resolutions.Then set `canvas` to `Screen Space - Overlay`. This render mode places UI elements on the screen rendered on top of the scene. If the screen is resized or changes resolution, the Canvas will automatically change size to match this.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the images to remain their sizes, instead of stretching along with the screen size.

Comment: Just set your panel to `Screen Space - Overlay` not your `images` or keep your images in `panel`

Comment: If it works then consider green tick!

Comment: Well... it does not work. I think you don't get what my problem is. If the aspect(ratio of width and length) of the screen changes, the animation will not start and end at the right place.

Comment: Because of your animation, which method are you using in animations. Timeline or core code.

Comment: The timeline tool, as you can see in screenshot 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203165/discussion-between-ahmed-ali-and-arts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, problem solved. It turns out the animation supports changing anchors at certain frames. So just turn on recording and adjust whatever you like.

In my project, first frame I set the finger image's anchor to the middle-lower point then record its position; when starts the moving animation, changes its anchor to middle-upper point then set the destination position. If the screen aspect ratio changes, since the animation also uses the right anchor data with the two check boxes, they'll match perfectly.

FYI, here's a screenshot of the animation window to help you understand.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may help,
[docs Unity3d site](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html)

This will support animations.